# Lookup - Search with Number

Tags: apex, community

I had created an Auto Number field on the Opportunity. (i.e whenever a new opportunity will create a number will assign to them)

Now i had created one Custom Object (INVOICE), under that i had creted one lookup field with opportunity, i want to somecondition or somthing, by which i can search the Opportunity with the opportunity number not with the opp name.

[image]

Comment: Enable Enhanced Lookup Search. It search for all fields by default. **EDIT** Sorry, I take my comment back. It does not search for all field. Anyhow [this link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=search_lookupdialog.htm&language=en) may help you.

Comment: @abdn - not working for me /

Comment: Have you added the AutoNumber field to your list views for Opportunity?

Comment: Yes - @crmprogdev